# OpenCV 2.4 : problems with includes in Qt in windows

Tags: windows, qt, opencv

I am not a C++ master (far from that actually), I try to setup an OpenCV + Qt project. I have downloaded the last release of OpenCV. I did nothing more with that (if I understand well, everything is pre-built, so I just have to add the path to the libs in my .pro file).

I added the path to the include folder /opencv/include

That should work that way, since the includes in cv.h, for example, are like that :

## include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"

However, when I browse through my opencv folder, opencv2 is empty, there is no core folder in it, nor anything else, actually there is just a header file, opencv.h .

I noticed that all my include are spread into several folders, under the module folder... what should I do??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my .pro file :

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = test_MTI880
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += ... ... ...

INCLUDEPATH += D:/PointGreyResearch/FlyCapture2/include \
        += D:/opencv/include

LIBS += D:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_core240.lib \
        D:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_highgui240.lib \
        D:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_imgproc240.lib \
        D:/opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/opencv_objdetect240.lib \
        D:/PointGreyResearch/FlyCapture2/lib/FlyCapture2.lib \
        D:/PointGreyResearch/FlyCapture2/lib/C/FlyCapture2_C.lib \
        D:/PointGreyResearch/FlyCapture2/lib/FlyCapture2d.lib \
        D:/PointGreyResearch/FlyCapture2/lib/FC1/PGRFlyCapture.lib
```

Comment: That would imply modifying opencv source code ! Such as cv.h, where the include are : #include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/flann.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
...

Comment: I guess I have to move manually the folders into the right directory ? Doesn't make any sense... :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to add those libraries in `.pro` file `module` wise, means you have to add all modules you are using in the project to `LIBS` variable in `.pro` file. Say if you are using modules libopencv1, libopencv2, libopencv3

LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lopencv1 -lopencv2 -lopencv3

like that.

If opencv libraries are added to `/usr/local/lib`, use `-L/usr/local/lib instead` of `-L/usr/lib`

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply, the libs do not seem to be the problem, it is rather the include, and I work with Windows not unix. Thx !

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer...

The right include folder is the one into the build folder ... -_-'

Comment: Did you do the build install step? you can then copy bin/inc/lib from the install folder to the opencv source if you want

Comment: In my understanding, you do not have to build anything if you plan to use Visual C++ compiler in your project. Everything you need comes prebuilt in the opencv/build folder. You have to go through the build install steps only if you wish to change some things or use another compiler such as migw.